# How to set external storage writing runtime permission in android with xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Hello and thanks in advance. I'm writing this question because I've been serching the internet for weeks now and i still can't find the answer to my question. I need to include runtime permissions in my android aplication but I can't find a workig way to do this. My main problem is that I don't know where to put the requestPermissions() function.

Comment: you generally request permission to do X when you user attempts to do something that requires X.  ExternalStorage is typically set in the ApplicationManifest, not at runtime

Comment: Have you considered this plugin? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to specified the permission that your app needs in **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

After that you need to ensure the  **Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat** NuGet package is included in your project because this package will backport permission specific APIs to older versions of Android.

If you are using Android 6.0 o later, you can check the permission or request in your activity using the method **ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission**

```
if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == (int)Permission.Granted) 
{
    // We have permission.
} 
else 
{
    // Storage permission is not granted. If necessary display rationale & request.
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I was missing te Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat NuGet Package and that is why it was not working.